# How to use BackgroundWorker with custom Progress Dialog (Form with ProgressBar)?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, progressdialog

I've got a method that loads files. Sometimes it takes a lot of time so I would like to show user a progressBar window, with which he can minimize the whole application or cancel the progress.

I've read bunch of tutorials about BackgroundWorkers and ProgressBars but none of these covers the scenario, when the ProgressBar is at some other Form. I don't know when exactly should I open the new form and how to access the progress bar there.

So far I've tried:

MainForm:

```
private void addFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ctlFolderSelectDialog dlg = new ctlFolderSelectDialog();
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(dlg); // to pass some variables from ctlFolderSelectDialog
    }
}

private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Form_Dialogs.ProgressDialog progressDialog = new Form_Dialogs.ProgressDialog();
    progressDialog.ShowDialog(); // open the progress dialog window

    myClass.loadFiles((ctlFolderSelectDialog)e.Argument); // THE WORK

    progressDialog.Close(); // close the progress window - in here?
}
```

myClass:

```
public void loadFiles(ctlFolderSelectDialog dlg)
{
    ...
    files.Count() // somehow report this preliminary number of files to ProgressBar window - to set ProgressBar1.Maximum value
    ...
    foreach (file in files)
    {
        loadFile();
        ... // here I should somehow udpate the progressBar on the other window - performStep()
    }
}
```

ProgressDialog:

```
private void ProgressDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100; // how to get this value from myClass function? Pass in ProgressDialog contructor?
    progressBar1.Step = 1;
}

public void UpdateProgress(int progress)
{
    progressBar1.PerformStep();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`BackgroundWorker` supports progress updates through the `ProgressChanged` event.

Inside the `loadFiles()` method you need to calculate the progress in % and inside the `foreach` loop call `backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(percentage)`. This will raise the `ProgressChanged` event from which you can get in the event arguments `e.ProgressPercentage`. [You will need a reference to the `BackgroundWorker` inside the `loadFiles()` method]

In the `ProgressDialog` form you need to register to this event. You can pass the `BackgroundWorker` in the constructor e.g.

```
public void ProgressDialog(BackgroundWorker worker)
{
   worker.ProgressChanged += ProgressDialog_ProgressChanged;
}

private void ProgressDialog_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   UpdateProgressBar(e.ProgressPercentage);
}
```

and in the main form:

```
private void addFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ctlFolderSelectDialog dlg = new ctlFolderSelectDialog();
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(dlg); // to pass some variables fromctlFolderSelectDialog
        Form_Dialogs.ProgressDialog progressDialog = 
           new Form_Dialogs.ProgressDialog(BackgroundWorker); // Pass the BackgroundWorker instance
        progressDialog.ShowDialog(); // open the progress dialog window
        // No need to explicitly close it. A dialog form is destroyed when closed by the user.
    }
}

private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    myClass.loadFiles((ctlFolderSelectDialog)e.Argument); // THE WORK
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the only problem now is, that it won't call: dataGridView_DataBindingComplete(), how can I do that? 

Btw myClass.loadFiles() loads the files to a list<> first and afterwards it puts the list into DataSet which is bound to the DataGridView. If I want the progress to go again from zero to measure the process of loading list<> into into DataSet, should I create another BackgroundWorker and start it in the first BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted() method? Or should I do both processes in one BackgroundWorker thread?

Comment: 1. Please give more details about dataGridView_DataBindingComplete() not being called. 2. Why would you want to show a progress bar for loading the files into the Dataset? Does it take more than 1 second? I would expect a few milliseconds.

Comment: I use TagLib library to read music ID3 tags. When calling myClass.loadFiles() it goes through given directory structure and fills List<TagLib>. This has a progress bar attached. Afterwards the method fillDataset is called which takes the list and for each item-song (could be 10 000) it reads ID3 information like song name, artist, length, .. and adds a row to the dataset. It usually takes the same time as crawling through the directory structure (~10 seconds).

Comment: dataGridView_DataBindingComplete() goes through every record (song) in the list and gives different background to every even row (zebra tables) and sets given row height to every one.

Comment: 1. The databinding problem is unrelated to this question. I suggest to open a new question with the relevant code. 2. I believe the easiest way is to create a new instance of `ProgressDialog`